# Understanding TypeScript template literal type with `${any}${any}`

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why this:

```js
type NotEmpty<T extends string> = T extends `${any}${any}` ? T : never;

declare function something<T extends string>(x: NotEmpty<T>): void;

something("hello")
something(""); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

achieves the obvious goal of the type and yet this does not:

```js
type NotEmpty<T extends string> = T extends `${string}${string}` ? T : never;

declare function something<T extends string>(x: NotEmpty<T>): void;

something("hello")
something(""); // okay
```

and also this does not:

```js
type NotEmpty<T extends string> = T extends `${any}` ? T : never;

declare function something<T extends string>(x: NotEmpty<T>): void;

something("hello")
something(""); // okay
```

Comment: It works because if you use `${string}${string}`, the two strings could be empty strings, matching an empty string. `${any}${any}` requires that there must be something there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the first one works to be honest: Intuitively, you'd think `''` extends `string` extends `any`.
¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Here's a working type that in case any future person needs one that is straightforward.

```
type NonEmpty<T extends string> = '' extends T ? never : T;
```

But this feels like cheating because it explicitly uses empty string and doesn't answer your question.

However, If you expand out either the `${any}${any}` or `${string}${string}` using `infer`, they both yield your expected result.

```
type NonEmpty<T extends string> = T extends `${infer First}${infer Rest}` ?
 First extends string ? Rest extends string ? T : never : never : never;
```

which only adds to my confusion. I know there are [some simplifications to types when it comes to template literals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42903#issuecomment-784366198). I think the best path to an answer would be to open an issue [on the Typescript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and hope that Anders (the Typescript guy) or someone on the team clarifies.